# C# MVVM - how doI prevent duplicated content in a multiple combobox selection?

Tags: c#, mvvm, combobox

I have five `ComboBox`s which are using the same enum content.
Each ComboBox should not have the same value.

If box one has selected content "beef", box two has selected the content "beer".

And now I select "beer" in box one, and both contents should switch. I'm actually using a method with checks both with if and else (working, but really boring).

Is there a smarter solution?

For each box I have one of this trigger and `Model.BoxOneValue`, `Model.BoxTwoValue`...

```
private void OnBoxOneChange(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: A solution is probably possible using `CommandParameter` could you post your `xaml` too?

Answer (score 0):

Can't post a full answer without that `xaml` but if you can pass it a `ComboBox` via `CommandParameter`

```
public RelayCommand<object> BoxChangeCommand { get { return new RelayCommand<object>(OnBoxChange); } }
private void OnBoxChange(Object comboBox)
{
    ComboBox list = comboBox as ComboBox;
    if (list != null) {
        //do stuff
        var items = list.Items;
        var selectedItem = list.SelectedItem;
    }
}
```

you'll need `using System.Windows.Controls` for the `ComboBox`

There is another way too, by binding your `SelectedItem` in the `xaml` to your VM and you can press a button on the frontend and the VM with figure everything out.